# A newline/linebreak issue when writing parsed text to .csv file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, macos, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Have an issue with parsing extracted text from html with BeautifulSoup and writing it to a .csv file.

Parsing a page with data such as **Title**, **Date**, **Description**, **Info**

I have a **Description** text example with exact structure parsed from a web page. It has those 
 tags and double spaces:

```
<p>Hello World <br/>
<br/>
Key points <br/>
<br/>
 -  Point number one  <br/>
 -  Point number two    <br/>
 -  Point number three  </p>
```

So I managed to extract it just as a text by using **.text.strip()** Now it's:

```
Hello World 

Key points 

 -  Point number one  
 -  Point number two    
 -  Point number three
```

Then I want to save results to a .csv file, each result to a new cell:

```
Title, Date, Description, Info
Title, Date, Description, Info
Title, Date, Description, Info
```

For this I'm creating a file, set headers and start writing in to it with FOR loop

```
filename = "scraping.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "Title, Date, Description, Info\n"
f.write(headers)
for article in articles:
    ...
    f.write(title + "," + date + "," + description + "," + info + "\n")
f.close()
```

And what I have at the end of it is the .csv file with all information.
The problem is when the **description** is passed to the file it's breaking all lines.

```
Title, Date, 
Des
crip
tion, Info
Title, Date, 
Des
crip
tion, Info    
Title, Date, 
Des
crip
tion, Info
```

If I write to the file everything except **description** all is good.

How do I save this **description** to a cell and ignore all unwanted newline/linebreak?

**UPDATE**:
Based on the suggestion from **@ewwink** this combination helped to remove unwanted linebreaks

```
description = re.sub(r"[\r\n]+", " ", description)
```

Unfortunately it was printed to the .csv file's cell in one single line without formatting. But I was able to make newlines in the .csv file with invisible pilcrow symbol by replacing **\r\n**

```
pilcrow = """
    """
description = re.sub(r"[\r\n]+", pilcrow, description)
```

Comment: Might be a be ugly, but for now did you try `f.write(title.strip() + "," + date.strip() + "," + description.strip() + "," + info.strip() + "\n")` to make sure the various strings are indeed clear of all line breaks?

Comment: Just before writing it to a file, can you print description?

Comment: Yes, and it will be just fine, no tags, just text with formatting

Comment: @Guimoute, text is already passed from the list `str(description[0].text.strip())` and it didn't help

Comment: nice find, just knew it maybe last time I try the error came from unecaped quotes. but still the secret is double quotes, try you can remove line of regex replace .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to save it as `.csv` file you need to double quote value so if there is  `,` it will not break your csv column and escape `"` with `""`

```
for article in articles:
    ...
    # description = re.sub(r"[\r\n]+", " ", description)
    description = description.replace('"', '""')
    rows = '"%s","%s","%s","%s"\n' % (title, date, description, info)
    f.write(rows)
```

Comment: Thank you **ewwink**, your suggestion is very helpful! 
I modified my code and tried to run it, now I have my .csv file almost correct. It did remove unwanted line breaks, but now it's (description block) written in one single line...
Is there a way to keep formatting in each cell? 
I have text with bullet points and would like to keep it as it is, instead of manually correcting

Comment: you cannot have new line in csv, but xls can. maybe you can replace newline with symbol later when needed replace it newline.

Comment: Once again, thanks for your suggestion, I managed to make newlines in my .csv file and updated my question with the solution.